# Exception thrown: 'Npgsql.NpgsqlException' in mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#, postgresql, crud

```
 connection.Open();
                query = "delete from validation where brandcode='@p1'";
                cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(query, connection);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", Convert.ToInt64(dataGridView2.Rows[rowIndex].Cells["brandcode"].Value.ToString()));
                if ((int)cmd.ExecuteScalar() == 1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("brandcode deleted successfully!");
                }
                
                connection.Close();
```

I'm doing deleting action with postgreSQL and C#. I have an error like:

```
Exception thrown: 'Npgsql.NpgsqlException' in mscorlib.dll
```

I can't see which makes me getting this error.

**Update**: I have edited code by removing the quotes near of the parameter in query and seen that brandcode column is string. So my edited code is:

```
connection.Open();
                query = "delete from validation where brandcode=@p1";
                cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(query, connection);
               
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", dataGridView2.Rows[rowIndex].Cells["brandcode"].Value.ToString());
                if ((int)cmd.ExecuteScalar() == 1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("brandcode deleted successfully!");
                    rowIndex = -1;
                    Select();
                }
                
                connection.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                connection.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Deleted Failed! Error:"+ ex.Message);
            }
```

The error in terminal is like:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.NullReferenceException' in postgrescrud.exe
```

When i reopen the app,i see that the query has worked. But how can i prevent this error?

Comment: Does that exception have a `.Message` or an InnerException, with more information?

Comment: Try `brandcode=@p1` (remove quotes around parameter)

Comment: Why are you doing a .ToString() followed by a Convert.ToInt64 of a value that's probably a string (even if it consists only of digits)? What is the datatype of that brandcode column?

Comment: @HansKesting i have removed quotes and i have seen that column is character varying type. Now i am changing the code

Comment: @HansKesting message is like that Exception thrown: 'System.NullReferenceException' in postgrescrud.exe

Comment: [Don't use .AddWithValue](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/), but create a parameter of the correct type (which apparently should not be Int64/long, as would be inferred now)